# selecting rows based on multiple column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Name": ["AAAA", "BBBB"],
        "C1": [25, 12],
        "C2": [2, 1],
        "C3": [1, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("Name")
```

which looks like this when printed (for reference):

```
      C1  C2  C3
Name            
AAAA  25   2   1
BBBB  12   1  10
```

I would like to choose rows for which `C1`, `C2` and `C3` have values between `0` and `20`.

Can you suggest an elegant way to select those rows?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think below should do it, but its elegance is up for debate.

```
new_df = old_df[((old_df['C1'] > 0) & (old_df['C1'] < 20)) & ((old_df['C2'] > 0) & (old_df['C2'] < 20)) & ((old_df['C3'] > 0) & (old_df['C3'] < 20))]
```

Comment: Is there a way to use 'or' other than '&'

Comment: Love the elegance note :D

Comment: Use | in place of & for an "or" condition.

Comment: Note that even after nearly 9 years, it still won't work without the parentheses (even for two conditions), and one could argue, that it would be more intuitive.

Comment: This can be simplified using the 'between' function. Than you can drop half the conditions and the parentheses.

`df[df['C1'].between(0, 20) & df[df['C2'].between(0, 20) & df[df['C3'].between(0, 20)]`

Answer (score 27):

Shorter version:

```
In [65]:

df[(df>=0)&(df<=20)].dropna()
Out[65]:
   Name  C1  C2  C3
1  BBBB  12   1  10
```

Answer (score 22):

I like to use df.query() for these kind of things

```
df.query('C1>=0 and C1<=20 and C2>=0 and C2<=20 and C3>=0 and C3<=20')
```

Answer (score 12):

A more concise `df.query`:

```py
df.query("0 <= C1 <= 20 and 0 <= C2 <= 20 and 0 <= C3 <= 20")
```

or

```py
df.query("0 <= @df <= 20").dropna()
```

Using `@foo` in `df.query` refers to the variable `foo` in the environment.